# Unable to get separate references during iteration

Tags: c#, reference, xna, iteration

I am attempting to iterate through the members of a list which implement a particular interface, called `ImplementsGraphics` and then call the method `GetModels` and add the return result to a list.

However, whenever I attempt to iterate through my objects, and perform the casting operation, I appear to be overwriting the same reference during my iteration. I have deduced that my problem is something to do with where, when and how I am instantiating my variables, but I can not decipher exactly what the intended behavior is.

I've tried numerous permutations of the following code:

```
public List<Model> GetModels()
        {
            var models = new List<Model>();

            foreach (Actor actor in registeredActors.Where(n=>n is ImplementsGraphics))
            {
                var graphicActor = (ImplementsGraphics)actor;
                models.AddRange(graphicActor.GetModels());
            }
            return models;
        }
```

The problem line is `var graphicActor = (ImplementsGraphics)actor;` but I don't know how to write it such that declaring graphicsActor does not overwrite the existing instances of it stored in models.

Before my first several rounds of troubleshooting, I had

```
public List<Model> GetModels()
        {
            var models = new List<Model>();

            foreach (Actor actor in registeredActors)
            {
                if((ImplementsGraphics)actor != null)
                    models.AddRange(((ImplementsGraphics)actor).GetModels());
            }
            return models;
        }
```

Which I expected to work, as I had thought `actor` was safe across iteration, but apparently not.

Desired Behavior:
Return a list, which is all the return results of `GetModels()` for ever Actor in RegisteredActors which implements `ImplementsGraphics`

Actual Behavior: 
Returns a list, which is the same return value repeated for each Actor in Registered Actor, which implements ImplementsGraphics.

**EDIT:**

In the class `StaticActor` which is a child of `Actor` and implements `ImplementsGraphics` its defined as follows:

```
public List<Model> GetModels()
    {
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.World = this.Transform.WorldMatrix;
            }
        }
        return new List<Model> { Model };
    }
```

Additonally, I have tried two other approaches which also failed. A for loop, which itereated through all of `RegisteredActors`, and checked if they implemented `ImplementsGraphics`, explicitly calling them by their index within `RegisteredActors`

And a LINQ query, which went 
`var models = RegisteredActors.Where(n=>n is ImplementsGraphics).SelectMany(n=>((ImplementsGraphics)n).GetModels())`

**EDIT 2:**

The deinfitions of my classes are largely irrelevant, if you want a reproducable example of the behaviour I'm having trouble with, here is a far simpler example.

```
class MyClass
{
    MyOtherClass foo = new MyOtherClass();
    int bar = 0;

    MyOtherClass GetOtherClass()
    {
        foo.bar = bar;
        return foo;
    }
}

class MyOtherClass
{
    int bar = 0;
}

List<MyClass> MyCollection = new List<MyClass> {new MyClass(bar = 1), new MyClass(bar = 2), new Myclass(bar = 3)};
List<MyOtherClass> MyOtherCollection = new List<MyOtherClass>();
foreach(MyClass member in MyCollection)
{
    MyOtherCollection.Add(member.GetOtherClass());
}
```

If you were to execute the above code, I expect that the value of MyOtherCollection's bar properties would be: 1, 2, 3

However, the actual result is that: 
During the first iteration the values are 1
During the second iteration the values are 2, 2
During the third iteration the values are 3, 3, 3

Comment: Is it possible they all implement the interface so this is why you get same result? You also talk about models, I see you are adding to it. Does it get from the same list when calling GetModels()?

Comment: The problem is not how you cast to that interface. Show an outline of graphicActor.GetModels().

Comment: @Aldert They do all implement the interface, but the implementation of the interface in the particular subclass of Actor that they all are (they all happen to be `StaticActor`s at this current moment of debugging) they should all have a unique return type. I have stepped through the code in debugging, and confirmed that each call to `GetModels()` is returning the proper unique values. The issue is the overwriting of the list `models`

Comment: @HenkHolterman it `public List<Model> GetModels()`

In general, it collects from the object on which it is defined, all `Model`s, sets the models' world matrix based on the `Transform` property of the Actor.

Theimplementation for `StaticActor` which is what I am debugging with is:
```
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
{
 foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
 {
   effect.World = this.Transform.WorldMatrix;
 }
}
return new List<Model> { Model };
```
Since all the members of `RegisteredActors` have different transforms, the results should all be different

Comment: You wrote: The problem line is var graphicActor = (ImplementsGraphics)actor; but I don't know how to write it such that declaring graphicsActor does not overwrite the existing instances of it stored in models. I believe a misconception on your side, nothing is overwritten here, you only cast to a new variable.

Comment: Either post a dressed down version of that GetModels() or write a [mcve]. Right now there is nothing answerable here.

Comment: @Aldert yes, the problem isn't the cast, the problem is setting the variable `graphicActor` which changes the members of `models`

On the first iteration, everything goes great. But then, the second time through, I am changing the value of the members already in `models`. The `GetModels` method does edit a property of the instance it exists on, but this edit is being reflected in all members of `models` not just in the current member during iteration.

Comment: I agree with @HenkHolterman, nothing answerable here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman and @Aldert I've included the implementation for `GetModels()` in `StaticActor` the class `Model` is the XNA model, whos definitions you can google.

Comment: model / Model ?  Where does it come from? We are getting closer, but don't post code that won't even compile.

Comment: `public Model Model` is a property of  the class `StaticActor` because the definitions of the subclasses of `Actor` are arbitrary, the `GetModels()` method is intended to extract the relevant information from the subclass.

`GetModels()` in the case of this debugging example, is intended to simply define the behavior which gets the `Model` property of StaticActor, without Actor having any definition for the property Model, and other contexts not needing to know which subclass it is, or even which subclasses exist

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've isolated the problem behavior, its in a new Edit. I've been over my class definitions, they're not the issue. I've check by stepping through them one at a time several times.

Comment: Your mock up does show the problem, there is only one instance of `MyOtherClass`. Not sure how that fits in with the real code, you may want to add an [xna] tag.

Comment: Yes, there's one instance. Thank you for dedicing exactly the issue. The question, is how to fix it. Reusing the same instance means over writing the existing values in the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would appear, since none of the provided code states, only implies, that you are attempting to reuse a reference to single `Model` instance to draw multiple objects. Then you are adding multiple references of the same instance to the `List`.

The solution may be as simple as removing the `static` modifier from all `Model` variables and/or container objects.

Normally, the solution would be to create a [Deep Copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy) of the object when it is added to the `List`, however, it is not directly possible to do this in `XNA` *1. (not that you would want to)

It would be better to allow each `Actor`, or `StaticActor`, object to directly pass its own `Model`(s) through the `GetModels()` method in the interface implementation, instead of using the additional class `MyOtherClass`.

*1.  `XNA` does not expose a public constructor for the [Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/xna/bb198095(v%3Dxnagamestudio.10)) class. It is *possible* to do this using reflection.  In `MonoGame`, there is a public [Constructor](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/ab0f2613d83da0ae11027e767860a4a4cd2fdfd7/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/Model.cs#L65) available.

---

I tend to split my derived Classes and subsequent `List`s based on properties like "StaticCollidables","DrawableStaticCollidables" and "DrawableMovingCollidables"...

This technique may require more upfront coding(and therefore is not as "elegant"), but, it is more efficient in terms of memory overhead(8 bytes + (4(32 bit) or 8(64 bit) bytes depending on `sizeof(Object)`) per [List](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs)) and CPU overhead(no casting or `is`).

---

If you are attempting to reuse the same model, but place it in different locations, use the [DrawInstancedPrimitives](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2010/06/17/drawinstancedprimitives-in-xna-game-studio-4-0/) method using the `VertexBuffer`s contained within each `Mesh` of the model.

---

Please comment on which of the above solutions worked for you(if any). If I have missed something please let me know, so I can correct the answer.

Comment: So, yes, after reading this over, I have discovered the root of the problem, and it was your mention of `DrawInstancedPrimatives` that tipped me off to what was causing it.

The issue is about how I was declaring the actors, where all the actors pointed to the same model (and effects) and as such, overwriting the model of one actor would effect all other actors. The issue was happening way elsewhere in code.